# Unbounded operators, Hilbert spaces and Borel sets

Tags: hilbert-spaces, borel-sets

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\langle , \rangle$ its inner product. Let $X : $ be a self-adjoint linear operator and let $F_X : H \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $F_X(a) = \langle a , Xa \rangle$. Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an open set. Is $F_X^{-1}(U)$ a Borel set (in the Borel algebra of the topology induced by the norm of the Hilbert space)?

From what I understand, if $X$ is bounded then it is continuous, therefore $F_X$ is continuous, therefore $F_X^{-1}(U)$ is an open set and therefore a Borel set.

What can I say in the unbounded case?

Answer (score 1):

May we assume that $X$ is a linear operator? If so then one has boundedness if and only if continuity as you describe. The missing step then would be show that that your self-adjoint operator is bounded using the Uniform Boundedness Principle. The rest follows by using the characterisation of a continuous map as one where the pre-image of open sets are open.

Let me elaborate on the UBP part:
Our goal is to show that $X$ is bounded as this implies the boundedness of $F_X$ and we're done. That is to say, we wish to show that $\sup_{\vert\ x \vert \leq 1}\vert\vert Xx \vert\vert < \infty$. To do this we start by defining the following family of linear operators $T_x:H\rightarrow H$ defined $T_x(y) := <Xx,y>_H$. One may show that for any choice of $x$ that these are bounded, in particular we have:
$\sup_{\vert y \vert \leq 1}\vert\vert T_x y \vert\vert = \sup_{\vert y \vert \leq 1}<Xx,y> = \vert\vert Xx\vert\vert$. Similarly, one may show that $\sup_{\vert x \vert \leq 1}\vert\vert T_x y \vert\vert = \sup_{\vert x \vert \leq 1}<Xx,y> = \sup_{\vert x \vert \leq 1}<x,Xy> = \vert\vert Xy\vert\vert$. Having satisfied the conditions of the UBP we conclude that $\vert X \vert := \sup_{\vert x \vert \leq 1}\vert Xx \vert = \sup_{\vert x\vert\leq 1, \vert y \vert \leq 1}\vert T_xy\vert < \infty$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, $X$ is linear (added to the description). The question is more about the unbounded case... maybe I am missing something, but how can I apply the Uniform Boundedness Principle in that case? There will be some points in $H$ for which $F_X$ will diverge.

Comment: I made an edit to the answer in the hope this clear things up

Comment: But $X$ _can_ be unbouded. Take $L^2$ and just $x$. $\int a^\dagger(x) x a(x) dx$ will diverge from some $a(x)$. My point is: if I assume $X$ to be bounded, I am fine. What can I say when $X$ is unbounded? For example, can I write $F_X^{-1}(U)$ as a limit of a sequence of open sets? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The point is that $X$ must be bounded since it is self adjoint and defined on a Hilbert Space. This what I show in the answer using the UBP. Remember that the definition of $A$ being a bounded operator is that that there exists some $\infty > c>0$ such that $\sup_{\vert x \vert \leq 1}\vert Ax \vert \leq c $

Comment: For $X$ self-adjoint to be defined on the whole Hilbert Space, yes $X$ must be bounded. But I am specifically interested in the case where $X$ is not bounded, and therefore it is not defined on the whole space... Is that the misunderstanding?